# Usage of geometryFilter in Planet.com API?

Tags: python, filter, planet

**Question:**
Where to put the GeoJSON filter AOI into the existing Python script I wrote to constrain (or clip) the image download?

**Setup:**
I was recently tasked with writing a Python script to download selected images for specified dates in a geographic AOI from Planet.com. A scientist will use the Planet.com viewer to select a number of images with a date stamp.  They create a list of these images. They want to have a script they double-click to download all the images on the list clipped to the AOI they created in GeoJSON. Script below does everything but constrain (or clip) the imagery.

**Problem:**
I keep getting full images, and I assume the scientists I work with are paying for every full image I download using this method, even though the GeoJSON AOI is a much smaller region.

**My Script:**

```
import os, requests, shutil, time

# Setup Globals
api_key = "fake_key"

session = requests.Session()

session.auth = (api_key, '')

planet_api_url = "https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/{}/items/{}/assets/"

# Use is CheckStatus(item_type,itemID,asset_type,"available")
def CheckStatus(itemType, itemID, assetType, checkValue):    
    status_Check = session.get((planet_api_url).format(itemType, itemID))
    print(str(status_Check))
# if checking for availability, will print out availability status
    if(checkValue == "available"):
        isAvailable = []
        for i in status_Check.json().iterkeys():
            isAvailable.append(i)
        canGet = assetType in isAvailable
        print("The " + str(assetType) + " availability status is " +  str(canGet))
        if(canGet):
            CheckStatus(itemType, itemID, assetType, "status")

# if checking for activation, will print out activation status
    elif(checkValue == "status"):    
        status_URL = status_Check.json()[assetType][filterType]["status"]    
        return_value = str(status_URL)    
        print("The status is: " + return_value)
        if(return_value == 'inactive'):
            CheckStatus(itemType, itemID, assetType, "activate")
        else:
            CheckStatus(itemType, itemID, assetType, "download")

# if checking for downloadable link, will download if activation has link
    elif(checkValue == "activate"):    
        item_activation_url = status_Check.json()[asset_type]["_links"]["activate"]    
        response = session.post(item_activation_url)    
        if(response.status_code == 202):    
            print(response.status_code)    
# This 5 second sleep probably isn't needed.  If the image isn't ready, the download will fail.    
            time.sleep(5)    
            CheckStatus(itemType, itemID, assetType, "download")    
        else:    
            print("Activation was not accepted")    
    elif(checkValue == "download"):    
        location_URL = status_Check.json()[assetType]["location"]    
        return_value = str(location_URL)    
        print(return_value)    
        # if the location has a length greater than 10 characters, run the download    
        if(len(return_value) > 10):    
            resp = requests.get(return_value, stream=True)    
            local_file = open(str(itemID) + "_download.tiff", 'wb')    
            resp.raw.decode_content = True    
            shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)    
            del resp             
        else:    
            print("Image isn't ready!")    
    return

# the geo json geometry object we got from geojson.io for AOI
geo_json_geometry = {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              177.17187881469727,
              -37.50768325920054
            ],
            [
              177.1607208251953,
              -37.51735099503349
            ],
            [
              177.1658706665039,
              -37.527289755696025
            ],
            [
              177.18114852905273,
              -37.53627434485652
            ],
            [
              177.19831466674805,
              -37.53355185637513
            ],
            [
              177.20552444458008,
              -37.525656077751094
            ],
            [
              177.20415115356445,
              -37.51367467967331
            ],
            [
              177.19385147094727,
              -37.50850029940243
            ],
            [
              177.18217849731442,
              -37.50659385835379
            ],
            [
              177.17187881469727,
              -37.50768325920054
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }

# filter for items the overlap with our chosen geometry
geometry_filter = {
  "type": "GeometryFilter",
  "field_name": "geometry",
  "config": geo_json_geometry
}

# For Testing:
# Type of asset
item_type = "PSScene4Band"
# ID value of image
item_id_list = "20200305_215235_103e"
# Type of data to activate and download
asset_type = "analytic"

CheckStatus(item_type,item_id_list,asset_type,"status")
```

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters (including the geometry filter) are for searching the catalog and finding images that match your criteria. Once found, the second step is to download (ignoring activation), and at this point you are downloading full images.

In your script, however, you've skipped the search step since someone is providing the imagery to you and jumping right to downloading. It is not possible to use `GeometryFilter` here.

Planet does offer another API called the Orders API, which can do clipping. You must request that it be enabled on your account. See documentation [here](https://developers.planet.com/docs/orders/).

Comment: Got it.  Filters only for searching and not clipping.  Thank you!